# JanusGraph in memory for testing

Tags: python, janusgraph

How can I create in memory graph for testing purposes in python, without needing to specifically configure gremlin server - similarly to [here](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/inmemorystorage.html)

`graph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set('storage.backend', 'inmemory').open()`

I'm using gremlin-python but there is no way of building the graph, rather connecting to one.

I may of course start and configure gremlin server with in-memory backend, then connect to it. But it seems redundant given I want to use in memory for testing purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JanusGraph is a graph database written in Java. There is no native Python implementation of JanusGraph, so you need to configure the Gremlin Server with a configuration that uses the `inmemory` storage backend.

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
storage.backend=inmemory
```

Check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/pluradj/7879df851c45269cd0cf8042955169f5) for more details on the full configuration.