# How to write unit tests for gremlin queries in Java?

Tags: unit-testing, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

for example connecting to client:

```
val client = Cluster.open(MapConfiguration(config)).connect()
```

and executing the query

```
client.submitAsync(PreparedStatement.addUser, map).await().all().join()
```

`PreparedStatement.addUser` - gremlin string

The question is: how to unit test client queries in Java. I thought of unit testing our queries with `inMemoryDB`. Can we run `inMemoryDB` as a client, because by default return `traversal()` if connecting to memory DB? Or can we execute a gremlin query string on `traversal`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sending Gremlin strings to Gremlin Server, you could treat your tests as integration tests and actually start a Gremlin Server instance with a [JanusGraph in-memory instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44638976/1831717) configured perhaps. In some cases, a TinkerGraph might suffice as well depending on what you need to test.

If you wanted more pure unit tests you would have to do some mocking, but that will be complicated as there are some non-public classes involved and the class dependencies are non-trivial. I think the first problem would be with the `ResultSet` and `ResultQueue` classes that the `Client` needs. I created this issue [TINKERPOP-2428](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2428).

I think that bytecode based requests are less challenging that scripts as you can mock the `RemoteConnection` to return your own `Traversal` instance. There is even an `EmbeddedRemoteConnection` that would let you define a local `GraphTraversalSource` to test against (if that situation suited you).